# Can Einstein STO delay subsequent email activities sent event in a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, einstein, process-automation

When Einstein STO is added to a journey, if 12hours are defined for  STO activity before email activities in this flow:

- email1 → wait 1day → email2 → wait 1day & email3.

If journey is activated / run at 5am.

Question 1)

If some subscriber's STO engagement time is between 4pm - 5pm. My understanding is that these subscribers won't get email1 at 5am and STO will hold these subscribers until 4pm-5pm window.

Because they will get to email1 activity between 4pm-5pm, does that mean the subsequent wait step will also start at 4pm-5pm, not 5am, which means subsequent emails may get delayed and well?
In other words, is STO step acting as a wait step in this case?

Question 2)

Can STO added in front of decision split or STO needs to be added individually in front of each email activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STO is a wait step so they will not continue in the journey till they exit the wait step so if they exit at 4pm they will go to the next activity at that time.

So in your example

STO > Email 1 > wait 1 day > email 2

the subscriber will leave at 4pm and get email 1 they will then wait 24hrs and leave the 1 day wait again at 4pm and get email 2

if you add another STO activity in front of email 2 they could leave at a different time depending on the configured window and the best time within that window

STO is not a queued emailed step.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Can STO added in front of decision split or STO needs to be added individually in front of each email activities?

Comment: Have you tried your desired use case? there is validation, so if its not allowed it would not validate